# What do you call a control that changes the relative sizes of two sections?

Tags: design-patterns, carousel

I want to implement a control to change the relative size of two sections within a single entity.  This would use an east-west resize cursor, and as the user dragged it would make one block smaller and the other larger.  The parent entity needs to remain the same size.

[image]

[image]

If possible I would like to search around and see if anybody else has already implemented a javascript control that does this.  However, I can't work out what to actually search for.

I have had a look at JQueryUI Resizables, Draggables and Sliders.  None of them are quite a perfect fit.

Do you know what this pattern is called?  Can you think of an implementation of this pattern in the wild (preferably web based)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a splitter (search for "splitter" on [43 Essential Controls for Web Apps](http://www.uxbooth.com/blog/essential-controls-for-web-applications/)).

It's not extremely common on the web, but it does exist in more than a few apps with a master-detail layout (e.g. Google reader). It is very common on the desktop though.

Comment: Fantastic Thanks!  A quick google has found me a few potential jquery implementations.